# How to get first record of each group created using groupBy() with Laravel eloquent model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table structured as following named **renewals**.

```
------------------------------------------------
| id  | membership_id| valid_from | valid_upto |
------------------------------------------------
|  1  | 1            | 2015-02-15 | 2016-02-15 |
|  2  | 2            | 2015-05-16 | 2016-05-16 |
|  3  | 2            | 2016-05-16 | 2017-05-16 |
|  4  | 3            | 2014-06-16 | 2015-06-16 |
|  5  | 3            | 2015-06-16 | 2016-06-16 |
|  6  | 3            | 2016-06-16 | 2017-06-16 |
|  7  | 1            | 2016-02-15 | 2017-02-15 |
------------------------------------------------
```

I need to get record of each members with latest **valid_upto** date. How to do that using Laravel Eloquent. Any other easy method will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

In User Model

```
public function latest_renewal()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Renewals', 'membership_id')->latest('valid_upto');
}
```

In controller

```
$users = User::with('latest_renewal')->get();
/*
 [
   {
     'id' => 1,
     'name' => 'user1',
     'latest_renewal' => {
         'id' => 7,
         'membership_id' => 1,
         'valid_from' => '2016-02-15',
         'valid_upto' => '2017-02-15',

     }
   },
   {
     'id' => 2,
     'name' => 'user2',
     'latest_renewal' => {
         'id' => 3,
         'membership_id' => 2,
         'valid_from' => '2016-05-16',
         'valid_upto' => '2017-05-16',

      }
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Renewals::groupBy('membership_id')->havingRaw('MAX(valid_upto)')->get();
```

or

```
Renewals::groupBy('membership_id')->having( function( $query )
{
    $query->latest('valid_upto');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain MySQL, you could get your latest records per member by following:

```
select a.*
from renewals a
left join renewals b on a.membership_id = b.membership_id
and a.valid_upto < b.valid_upto
where b.membership_id is null
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a97bd/1)

Using Laravel, you could write it using query builder as:

```
DB::table('renewals as a')
  ->select('a.*')
  ->leftJoin('renewals as b', function ($join) {
        $join->on('a.membership_id','=','b.membership_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.valid_upto < b.valid_upto'));
   })
  ->whereNull('b.membership_id')
  ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something simlilar to this

```
DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");

Renewal::groupBy('membership_id')
         ->latest('valid_upto')
         ->get();
```

Read more about the first SET SQL_MODE: [Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Renewal::get();
$groups = $data->groupBy('membership_id');
$results = [];
foreach($groups as $group) {
   /*collection*/
   $results[] = $group[0];
}
return $results;
```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731825/13381751

Answer (score -1):

You can use below query for your purpose.

```
$renewals = Renewals::groupBy('membership_id')->orderBy('valid_upto','desc')->get();
```

Comment: This gets all records, which is not what OP asked for.